# SOX producing "poping" or "crackling" noise after padding operation

Tags: sox

I'm trying to pad the beginning of a .wav file with silence using the following command

```
    sox infile.wav padded.wav pad 14 0
```

However, at second 14 (where the silence padding ends), there's a very egregious popping noise not found in the original .wav file. I'm running this command on Ubuntu 11. Any thoughts as to why this is occurring and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the beginning of your wav file starts with a sample value that is neither zero, nor close to it, and your playback system employs an anti-popping algorithm when starting playback (which of course, has no effect with the padding, since the pop is then 14 seconds in, instead of at the start).  You can check the waveform in audacity to see if this is the case.

Try

```
sox infile.wav padded.wav fade h 0.005 pad 14 0
```

and see if that solves the problem.